# Yii2 - strpos(): Empty needle in PhpMessageSource.php on line 111

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, php-7.2

Please find below Stack Trace I pasted from apache error logs.

```
An Error occurred while handling another error:\nyii\\web\\HeadersAlreadySentException: Headers already sent. in /var/www/html/staging_v2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php:373\nStack trace:\n#0 
/var/www/html/staging_v2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php(346): yii\\web\\Response->sendHeaders()\n#1 
/var/www/html/staging_v2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/ErrorHandler.php(136): yii\\web\\Response->send()\n#2 
/var/www/html/staging_v2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/ErrorHandler.php(135): yii\\web\\ErrorHandler->renderException(Object(yii\\base\\ErrorException))\n#3 
[internal function]: yii\\base\\ErrorHandler->handleException(Object(yii\\base\\ErrorException))\n#4 

{main}\nPrevious exception:\nyii\\base\\ErrorException: strpos(): Empty needle in /var/www/html/staging_v2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/i18n/PhpMessageSource.php:111\nStack trace:\n#0 
[internal function]: yii\\base\\ErrorHandler->handleError(2, 'strpos(): Empty...', '/var/www/html/s...', 111, Array)\n#1 
/var/www/html/staging_v2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/i18n/PhpMessageSource.php(111): strpos('en-US', '')\n#2 
/var/www/html/staging_v2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/i18n/PhpMessageSource.php(78): yii\\i18n\\PhpMessageSource->loadFallbackMessages('yii', '', NULL, '/var/www/html/s...')\n#3 /var/www/html/staging_v2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/i18n/MessageSource.php(107): yii\\i18n\\PhpMessageSource->loadMessages('yii', NULL)\n#4 
/var/www/html/staging_v2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/i18n/MessageSource.php(87): yii\\i18n\\MessageSource->translateMessage('yii', '{attribute} can...', NULL)\n#5 
/var/www/html/staging_v2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/i18n/I18N.php(90): yii\\i18n\\MessageSource->translate('yii', '{attribute} can...', NULL)\n#6 
/var/www/html/staging_v2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(538): yii\\i18n\\I18N->translate('yii', '{attribute} can...', Array, NULL)\n#7 
/var/www/html/staging_v2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/validators/RequiredValidator.php(62): yii\\BaseYii::t('yii', '{attribute} can...')\n#8 
/var/www/html/staging_v2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/BaseObject.php(109): yii\\validators\\RequiredValidator->init()\n#9 
[internal function]: yii\\base\\BaseObject->__construct(Array)\n#10 
/var/www/html/staging_v2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(420): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)\n#11 
/var/www/html/staging_v2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(171): yii\\di\\Container->build('yii\\\\validators\\\\...', Array, Array)\n#12 
/var/www/html/staging_v2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(365): yii\\di\\Container->get('yii\\\\validators\\\\...', Array, Array)\n#13 
/var/www/html/staging_v2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/validators/Validator.php(231): yii\\BaseYii::createObject(Array)\n#14 
/var/www/html/staging_v2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Model.php(469): yii\\validators\\Validator::createValidator('yii\\\\validators\\\\...', Object(frontend\\models\\ContactForm), Array, Array)\n#15 /var/www/html/staging_v2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Model.php(421): yii\\base\\Model->createValidators()\n#16 
/var/www/html/staging_v2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Model.php(190): yii\\base\\Model->getValidators()\n#17 
/var/www/html/staging_v2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Model.php(817): yii\\base\\Model->scenarios()\n#18 
/var/www/html/staging_v2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Model.php(435): yii\\base\\Model->activeAttributes()\n#19 
/var/www/html/staging_v2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Model.php(495): yii\\base\\Model->getActiveValidators('name')\n#20 
/var/www/html/staging_v2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/widgets/ActiveField.php(929): yii\\base\\Model->isAttributeRequired('name')\n#21 
/var/www/html/staging_v2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/widgets/ActiveField.php(405): yii\\widgets\\ActiveField->addAriaAttributes(Array)\n#22 
/var/www/html/staging_v2/frontend/views/site/index.php(143): yii\\widgets\\ActiveField->textInput(Array)\n#23 
/var/www/html/staging_v2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php(348): require('/var/www/html/s...')\n#24 
/var/www/html/staging_v2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php(257): yii\\base\\View->renderPhpFile('/var/www/html/s...', Array)\n#25 
/var/www/html/staging_v2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/View.php(213): yii\\base\\View->renderFile('/var/www/html/s...', Array, Object(frontend\\controllers\\SiteController))\n#26 /var/www/html/staging_v2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Controller.php(53): yii\\web\\View->renderAjax('index', Array, Object(frontend\\controllers\\SiteController))\n#27 /var/www/html/staging_v2/frontend/controllers/SiteController.php(555): yii\\web\\Controller->renderAjax('index', Array)\n#28 
[internal function]: frontend\\controllers\\SiteController->actionIndex()\n#29 
/var/www/html/staging_v2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#30 
/var/www/html/staging_v2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(181): yii\\base\\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)\n#31 
/var/www/html/staging_v2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(534): yii\\base\\Controller->runAction('index', Array)\n#32 
/var/www/html/staging_v2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(104): yii\\base\\Module->runAction('site/index', Array)\n#33 
/var/www/html/staging_v2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(392): yii\\web\\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\\web\\Request))\n#34 
/var/www/html/staging_v2/frontend/web/index.php(0): yii\\base\\Application->run()\n#35
```

You can find the issue here: https://staging-v2.storna.app
Admin Portal works https://staging-v2.storna.app/admin
API works too

Only landing pages have an issue.. it was working fine earlier.

What could be the issue?

There are only 2 issues in log. and 1 of which is warning and another is just a php7 notice. so I doubt it is due to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using `2.0.40` version and this was already reported [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/18464). It seems the Problem only exists on PHP Version `7.1 - 7.4` as `PHP 8.0` seems to pass successful with the reason being

> Looks like the previous versions were resilient to `language` being set to `null`

You can either change your `minimum-stability` settings in the `composer.json` from `stable` to `dev`, and run `composer update` to update your yii framework to dev-master.

Or you can manually update those files only from this [commit](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/commit/684310828b38452516e18c1222328e4b32527187)

I would use the second option as the first one will update all the packages too.